# Interactive Gantt chart using primefaces

Tags: interactive, gantt-chart

Can anyone suggest me how to create interactive gantt chart in  ejb 3.1 application.
I need to display interactive gantt chart using jsf. 
I am using primefaces 3.4.2 and primefaces extensions 0.6.2.

Thanks&Regards,
Nadhiya Shanmugam.

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of PrimeFaces include a [timeline component](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/timeline/basic.xhtml). I could not find when it was added exactly, but I believe at was added in PrimeFaces 6.

Events in the [custom example](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/timeline/custom.xhtml) have end dates, which makes the events to be rendered as bars.